# RSA Decryption problem involving large numbers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, contest-math, computer-science

I'm trying to decrypt a message.

this formula was used to encrypt it:

M^e(mod n)= encrypted message

my goal is to find what M is which is the message.

N=(public key) 1522605027922533360535618378132637429718068114961380688657908494580122963258952897654000350692006139

N can be factored N=P*Q

P: 37975227936943673922808872755445627854565536638199

Q: 40094690950920881030683735292761468389214899724061

e= 13

the encrypted message is: 758528843274794301509192367882543959039737059391624635306413623042673893239198184889915573690060317

how would you decrypt this message? I have tried running these numbers through a program but the numbers are too big for the computer to compute. I'm not sure how to approach this problem.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Use a CAS like Maple.